# How to read multiple scanf input in C in one line? say 200 Merck 58.9?

Tags: c

I am new to this, please forgive me if my question has issues.

I would like to read in an integer, a character array (say size 30), and a floating point number in C. How do I read all of it in one line in C, say 200 Merck 58.9? I have tried using scanf consecutively in the following, but the second scanf is not working - the space between input (e.g. 200 Merck 58.9) is causing mayhem.

```
printf("Please enter an integer, one word string, and a float in one line");

scanf("%i", &any_integer);

scanf("%29s", &any_string); // no spaces - just a one word string

scanf("%f", &any_float);
```

I would then like to test what the user enters, ensure that the integer and float is positive and not above 50, and in the string ignore anything that is not a character. Here is a start for the integer.

```
/* Test the input */

while(any_integer < 0 || any_integer > 50)
{
   printf("\n*** Invalid integer.\n Please enter a value between 1 and 50: 
   ");
   scanf("%i", &any_integer);

}/* end while */

while(any_float < 0)

{
   printf("\n*** Invalid float.\n Please enter a positive value: ");
   scanf("%f", &any_float);

}/* end while */
```

I would like to put this setup in an infinite while loop that terminates with 999, but i am struggling with the details laid out above.

Comment: 1. Have you read the manual page for `scanf`? 2. Where is the declarations for any_XXXX?

Comment: scanf isn't very useful unless you know exactly how data will come in. Not great for user input.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you pass the address of `any_string`, which is incorrect, and may cause undefined behavior is `any_string` is a pointer to a `char` array.  You should write:

```
scanf("%29s", any_string);
```

To improve error handling and improve input control, I suggest you read the line with `fgets()` and attempt parse with `sscanf()`. If the format is incorrect, you can restart with a new line:

```
int i1;
char s1[30];
float f1;

printf("Please enter an integer, one word string, and a float in one line\n");
for (;;) {
    char buf[100];
    char c;

    if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "premature end of file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (sscanf(buf, "%i%29s%f%c", &i1, s1, &f1, &c) != 4 || c != '\n') {
        printf("Invalid input, enter a new line\n");
        continue;
    }
    if (i1 < 0 || i1 > 50 || f1 < 0 || f1 > 50) {
        printf("Invalid values: must be between 0 and 50, try again\n");
        continue;
    }
    /* input values are correct */
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

```
char s[30];
int i;
float f;
while (true) {
   if (scanf(" %d%29s%f", &i, s, &f) == 3) {
      printf("%d%s%F", i, s, f);
   } else{
     // Sort out incorrect input
     // Eat up to the new line
     scanf("%*[^\n]");
     if (feof(stdin)) {
        // Do summat here - break perhaps
     }
   }
}
```

is what you require

Comment: *sorting out incorrect input* is going to be difficult. I guess you can read and discard the remaining characters up to and including the pending newline.

Comment: Did not seem that difficult

Comment: Yep, a simple solution indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You can just put them in one line like that:

```
scanf("%i %29s %f", &any_integer, any_string, &any_float);
```